# SQLite vs SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

Would any one please differentiate what is best to use SQLite or SQL Server? I was using XML file as a data storage ADD, delete , update.. Some one suggested to use SQLite for fast operation but I am not familier with SQLite I know SQL Server.

Comment: It's also a bit of a false comparison. Are you comparing db-in-a-single-file solutions (e.g., SQLite, MS Access) versus "real" RDBMSs (e.g., Oracle, SQLServer, PostgreSQL, MySQL)? Are you just comparing things with "SQL" in the name? ;-) There are so many criteria you're ignoring here (open source versus commercial--SQLServer is commercial, for instance, while SQLite is open source); typed columns versus untyped columns (SQLite columns are essentially untyped); scalable versus small-scale; etc.

Comment: @Breakhead, if this is for your personal use or if writes to the database are not made concurrently by multiple users, and if security of the data is not a concern, SQLite will probably do fine, even with gargantuan amounts of data. You can think of SQLite as a substitute for the MS-Access "JET" data engine; it is not a bona-fide client-server database engine like SQLServer or Oracle.

Comment: You might consider persisting stateful objects. I have been using this technique and it works quite well. When I tried to replace the persisted stateful objects with SQLite I found SQLite to be much slower - so much so that I had to scrap it altogether and go back to the persisted stateful objects.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

SQLite is a great embedded database that you deploy along with your application.  If you're writing a distributed application that customers will install, then SQLite has the big advantage of not having any separate installer or maintenance--it's just a single dll that gets deployed along with the rest of your application.

SQLite also runs in process and reduces a lot of the overhead that a database brings--all data is cached and queried in-process.

SQLite integrates with your .NET application better than SQL server.  You can write custom function in any .NET language that run inside the SQLite engine but are still within your application's calling process and space and thus can call out to your application to integrate additional data or perform actions while executing a query.  This very unusual ability makes certain actions significantly easier.

SQLite is generally a lot faster than SQL Server.

However, SQLite only supports a single writer at a time (meaning the execution of an individual transaction).  SQLite locks the entire database when it needs a lock (either read or write) and only one writer can hold a write lock at a time.  Due to its speed this actually isn't a problem for low to moderate size applications, but if you have a higher volume of writes (hundreds per second) then it could become a bottleneck.  There are a number of possible solutions like separating the database data into different databases and caching the writes to a queue and writing them asynchronously.  However, if your application is likely to run into these usage requirements and hasn't already been written for SQLite, then it's best to use something else like SQL Server that has finer grained locking.

**UPDATE:** SQLite 3.7.0 added a new journal mode called Write Ahead Locking that supports concurrent reading while writing.  In our internal multi-pricess contention test, the timing went from 110 seconds to 8 seconds for the exact same sequence of contentious reads/writes.

Comment: I would only the dispute the opinion that "SQLite integrates with your .NET application *better* than SQL server". [emphasis added] Both can be integrated with a .NET application though in different ways.  You can define CLR classes in SQL Server and send instances of these classes between client and server. In SQlite, you can create custom UDFs in a .NET language which can be imported into SQLite. Also, a phrase like "low to moderate size applications" is really meaningless. What do you mean by "size"?

Comment: @Tim, I specifically called out low to moderate as requiring up to *hundreds of writes per second*.  Above that amount contention becomes too problematic.

Comment: Hello Samuel, is sqlite supports all the functions of sql? OR not because of light weight architecture limit the function uses.

Comment: @BipinVayalu, no, SQLite does not support all of the functionality of SQL Server.  SQLite is a far more basic implementation.  It supports everything I've ever needed though.  :-)

Comment: On a single processor, in the case of multiple "simultaneous writes" would you expect a significant difference in timing between SQLite and an SQL implementation that supports concurrent writes?

Comment: @JesseW.Collins See the update for SQLite 3.7.0. It supports multiple writes now and my concurrent writing test sped up significantly--same test went from 110 seconds to 8 seconds.

Comment: I'd like to see a lot of these facts backed up. Like, SQLite is "faster" than SQL Server. SQLite also doesn't seem to support some basic functionality of SQL syntax like RIGHT JOIN, Joining on SUBQUERIES, etc. Also, in 2023, I really disagree with SQLite being a better choice for a .NET app. This answer is too far outdated to be useful.

Comment: @JacobH It's been 13 years so I don't have the data in front of me (I haven't touched .NET in a decade). Note the OP is talking about moving from an XML file, so the data is small and it's likely a single-user system, desktop or embedded. In those situations, SQLite is certainly better in many ways, including faster for the vast majority of queries (keeping in mind my experience is from 13 years ago). No `right join`, so use `left join`? Joining on subqueries works fine, even correlated joins.

Comment: Again, going need evidence to back any of that up. Specifically the "my 13 year old anecdotes say SQLite is faster". In what ways? How could it be faster for writes if it only supports single user concurrency? These statements conflict with each other.

Comment: @JacobH I don't need evidence. It's my statement and my experience. You can believe it or not or do whatever you want with the statement. I know it's true, it doesn't bother me whether or not you believe it. I've seen it. It may not be true in every situation, but it's true in the situations I cared about which match our real world use cases for our applications.

Comment: In our tests, SQLite wasn't just faster. It was very significantly faster. In our application I had logging setup to send me personally an email any time any query took more than 250ms in production. In 7 years I was there with this application running I received less than 5 emails. The enterprise work I do now with SQL Server and Postgres often has the developers struggling to deal with a 30 second timeout.

Answer (score 4):

Both are in different league altogether. One is built for enterprise level data management and another is for mobile devices (embedded or server less environment). Though SQLite deployments can hold data in many hundred GBs but that is not what it is built for.

Updated: to reflect updated question:
Please read [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20120417230445/http://pradeepgururani.blogspot.com/2010/01/sqlite.html) on SQLite. I hope that would help you and let you access it from redirect you to resources to programatically access SQLite from .net.

Comment: the link to the blog post is dead.