# SQLite vs. SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, sqlite

I created an application in C# using Winforms which has daily transaction of 2000 rows of data per day. I'm using SQL Server 2012 but I'm trying to use SQLite because of his fame and most people refer this

So, can you give me some ideas which one is better for my needs?

Thanks

Comment: If you need to have **multiple clients** connecting to the same data at the same time --> use the server-based SQL Server. If it's more about storing local data for a single user on his local machine --> SQLite has an edge

Comment: yes i have multiple user i think 10 to 20 user at a time using my app and some r working on same form
thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite integrates with your .NET application better than SQL server

SQLite is generally a lot faster than SQL Server.

However, SQLite only supports a single writer at a time (meaning the execution of an individual transaction). SQLite locks the entire database when it needs a lock (either read or write) and only one writer can hold a write lock at a time. Due to its speed this actually isn't a problem for low to moderate size applications, but if you have a higher volume of writes (hundreds per second) then it could become a bottleneck. There are a number of possible solutions like separating the database data into different databases and caching the writes to a queue and writing them asynchronously. However, if your application is likely to run into these usage requirements and hasn't already been written for SQLite, then it's best to use something else like SQL Server that has finer grained locking.

Comment: "SQLite integrates with your .NET application better than SQL server" - why? Without facts this seems an opinion-based answer.

Comment: "SQLite is generally a lot faster than SQL Server." - in which scenarios? Without a benchmark this seems an opinion-based answer.

Comment: The first two lines of this answer completely lack citation and, in my opinion invalidate the credibility of this answer.

Comment: The answer almost looks copy and pasted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539542/sqlite-vs-sql-server :D

Answer (score 3):

SQLite is a nice fast database to use in standalone applications. There's dozens of GUI's around to create the schema you want and interfaces for pretty much any language you would want (C#/C/C++/Java/Python/Perl). It's also cross platform and is suitable for Windows, Linux, Mac, Android, iOS and many other operating systems.

Here are some advantages for SQLite:

- **Perfomance**
- In many cases at least 2-3 times faster than MySQL/PostgreSQL.
- No socket and/or TCP/IP overhead - SQLite runs in the same process as your application.
- **Functionality**
- Sub-selects, Triggers, Transactions, Views.
- Up to 281 TB of data storage.
- Small memory footprint.
- Self-contained: no external dependencies.
- Atomic commit and rollback protect data integrity.
- Easily movable database.
- **Security**
- Each user has their own completely independent database(s).

Comment: I would suggest you to also add the disadvantages. All databases have pros and cons.