# C#: methode for storing large and complex data?

Tags: c#

I am trying to store a software "Calender"(complex logs that saved and browsed based on date).

I tried using both .ini and xml but when the application tried to read the entire file to find info for 1 specific day out of the 100 days (or so it seemed), it took almost 9 seconds to get 5 variables out of 500 variables. The size of the actual file might eventually be more than 40 variables per day.

Also, I would rather not make a file for each day, that will seems a little bit unprofessional and messy.

I am asking the question to know if there is an alternative to keep things fast and neat. The data includes different types of variables and different amounts of them.  I know i am kinda overdoing it with logging thing but the program needs logs to do its work

Comment: What stops you from using RDBMS (SQL db)?

Comment: Sounds like you need a lightweight database like SQLite

Comment: Why would you rather not store a file per day?

Comment: @m_wilczynski i havn't tried it,i personally perfer to parse text files so i can try to modify the parsing and saving faster. also i am trying learn a methode so maybe i can make a whole new format for this kind of files

Comment: @Enigmativity my date might look a lot like most video game save files, and i am trying to do what they did. and it's not a bad thing to do i am just trying to make it look more porfasinal for some one who look insed the folder in their documant folder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data must be stored it has to be a file or a database (local or remote), I'd go for SQLite, it would end in a single file, but you could query the data with SELECT, JOIN, etc.

EDIT:
You can use SQLite3 from c# if you include this package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/

You'll need to learn some SQL, but after that you'll just use something like:

```
select Message from Logs where Date > '2015-11-01' and Date < '2015-11-25';
```

which is easier, faster and clearer than messing with XML, and it will not load the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, SQLite will offer a great possibility. Since you (generally), and probably not a lot of people out here will be able to write a database management system that is as efficient as the ones out there.

https://www.sqlite.org

Comment: i am actully trying to learn how to do what Sql does, ilitrating for a entry without reading the whole file. do you know how to do something like that in C#?

Comment: This will help you out; http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/

Answer (score 1):

Whole point of using RDBMS because it's far more efficient that dealing with files.

SQL Lite is light weight and easier to deploy. But remember that,

> SQLite only supports a single writer at a time (meaning the execution
>   of an individual transaction). SQLite locks the entire database when
>   it needs a lock (either read or write) and only one writer can hold a
>   write lock at a time. Due to its speed this actually isn't a problem
>   for low to moderate size applications, but if you have a higher volume
>   of writes (hundreds per second) then it could become a bottleneck.
>   Reference [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539542/sqlite-vs-sql-server)

If this is an enterprise level application requirement I would go for Azure Table storage based solution which is identical for this sort of scenario.