# Using SQLite or SQL with PHP

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am working on an android project that uses an offline database. When it is connected to internet, the database should be updated. Another one of my requirements is that the database should be able to connect to SAP. Which database is better to use? SQLite or SQL with PHP? Any suggestions?

Comment: I up voted this post because you are new and I don't want you to ruin your rep as I did myself when I was newbie here. 
Now my advice is that you will delete this post and try to find in google whats the differences between SQL and SQLite... Next time you write a question pay more time to researching the topic you are posting about.
There are plenty of answers to this specific question on google.

Comment: If you are writing your app in Xamarin using C#, there is a way to connect to an SQL Server Database and retrieve information to store it locally. When the user is offline, he will be able to access the latest information and make changes to it. This can be stored using an SQLite database. When the user connect's to the Internet, any new information is synchronised with the SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to create a database on a server, you should probably go with MySQL (SQL is the query language, MySql is one of the most widely used database engines). According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539542/sqlite-vs-sql-server) thread, SQLite will only support one writer at a time and is not mean for "enterprise level" data management. However, it is faster and has less overhead, so if you did need a db on your mobile application, I would go with SQLite

Comment: This is a good option.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite is a lightweight version for mobile so it is the best choice for an offline mode.

Firebase is used to store data online and sync them with every connected clients.

See firebase.google.com

There is a *Getting started* section for Android, iOS and web platforms.